# Angle trisection of $90^o$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, angle

Read on page #7 of article [here](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/eqns_3.pdf), that angle of $90^o$ can be trisected. I went through this youtube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Vshz0kqZh4), and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJP9Z39PwjI); and denote these two videos (denoting two separate methods) by (a), (b) respectively. These use elementary methods used in school days, but were never explained for the reason.

Anyway, I want to understand the logic behind both (a), (b) as it is a valid trisection.

In (a) there is an arc equal to the length of the radius, let $|r|$. Now, I hope that it is an approximation as there should be (as per me) no way to get the $\frac{2}{3}: \frac{1}{3}$ on the $90^o$ arc. It is only the chord joining the two ends (let, $yx$ with $y$ the coordinate on the $y$-axis, and $x$ the coordinate on the $x$-axis) that can be hoped to be approximately divided by the arc from point $y$ or $x$. Either end's arc will cut the hypotenuse $yx$ in two parts with ratios $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}= 0.707, 1-0.707=0.293$ in opposite sides from point $y,x$ respectively. So, if I am not wrong, it is an approximate approach and hence not mathematically or even geometrically valid.

Approach shown in (b) is even difficult to understand, and would request some help, as it is using a chord's division (named $DE$) in two parts (at midpoint $F$) by the angle bisector of $90^o$ to derive further angle bisections on both sides of the midpoint $F$. I am unable to comprehend even the mechanism in this approach, as the average of $45^o $ and $90^o$ is $67.5^o$, while the average of $0^o$ and $45^o$ is $22.5^o$.

Also, both of the above methods are faulty, then please give some link for correct way.

---

*Edit* Unable to understand, and hope that the approach (a) is valid, as a similar approach is used [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=zXwQGo8jyHUC&pg=PA53&dq=trisecting%2090%20degree%20angle%20using%20ruler%20compass&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidhuD7zqzaAhURS48KHXpbB2QQ6AEIRjAG#v=onepage&q=trisecting%2090%20degree%20angle%20using%20ruler%20compass&f=false), in Fig. 3.13. But, am unable to understand that too, but being a credible reference source, can infer (a) is at least a valid one.

---

*Edit 2* I am posting an image of the reference in the 'Edit' made earlier, for a different, but linked question. It is given on the earlier page (#53) that on bisecting the smaller angle $\widehat {AON}$ obtained by bisecting, get the trisection. By this logic, the approach (b) is also valid. But, how can it be understood, is not clear, as double bisection to lead to $\frac{1}{4}$th of the original angle.

[image]

---

*Edit 3* Regarding bisection leading to trisection, have found a suitable basic geometrical technique at: http://www.lamath.org/journal/Vol1/trisection_using_bisection.pdf, on pg. #3,4, by using the two unequal circles' intersection formed from the bisection of the original interval.

The article titled: 'Trisection using Bisection' describes also the nth-section of any interval using unmarked ruler and collapsing compass, in the last section.

Comment: It is easy to construct a $30$ degree angle...just construct an equilateral triangle and bisect an angle.

Comment: @lulu I wanted trisection, not bisection. Also, above all why are these two approaches valid.

Comment: Constructing a 30 degree angle is equivalent to trisecting a 90 degree angle.

Comment: You start with a $90^\circ$ angle, and you construct a $30^\circ$ angle. Whether you actively _use_ that $90^\circ$ angle during the construction is actually somewhat irrelevant. When we say that in general trisecting an angle is impossible we don't mean that in the sense of "Starting with a given angle, there is no way to use that to construct a third of that angle", we actually mean the somewhat stronger statement "there are some constructable angles for which a third of that angle is not constructible in any way" (at least, that's how it was proven).

Comment: @Arthur Could not understand. Please elaborate, as I hope you are referring to the approach in (a). Also, this approach is presented in a different way here: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=zXwQGo8jyHUC&pg=PA53&dq=trisecting+90+degree+angle+using+ruler+compass&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidhuD7zqzaAhURS48KHXpbB2QQ6AEIRjAG#v=onepage&q=trisecting%2090%20degree%20angle%20using%20ruler%20compass&f=false

Comment: @jiten I'm not referring to your approaches at all. I'm just expanding on what lulu said: Constructing a $30^\circ$ angle is _the same as_ trisecting a $90^\circ$ angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First on method (a):

[image]

When you draw the first arc, we have $BD=BQ$ and then using the same radius, we have $DQ=BD=BQ$, hence $\triangle BQD$ is equilateral. Hence $\angle DBQ = 60^\circ$ and $\angle QBE = 90^\circ - \angle DBQ = 30^\circ$. By symmetry, $\angle DBP = 30^\circ$ too and $\angle PBQ = 30^\circ$.

For method $(b)$:

If I understand it correctly, it doesn't work.

[image]

Suppose all radius chosen is $1$, then $D$ and $E$ lies on the unit circle. By construction of $F$, $D, E, F$ lies on the line $x+y=1$. Then an arc is drawn from $F$ and another is drawn from $E$. These arcs has equation $(x-0.5)^2+(y-0.5)^2=1$  and $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$. If the claim is correct, let the intersection of the arc be $A$ then $\angle ABC$ should form $30^\circ$, however, if this is the case, point $A$ should lies on the straight line $y= \tan\left( \frac{\pi}6 \right)x$. So go to any graphic software and plot out those curve and we can find that it is not the case that the straight line (black line in my plot) passes through point $A$ ( The intersection of purple and orange arc).

[image]

A comment about the title of method $(b)$, if I am not mistaken, it has been proven previously that we can't  trisect an arbitrary angle.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is only the title in (b) which is unclear about trisecting a right angle, and yes it is a known proof that arbitrary trisection is not possible unless the algebraic operation corresponding to linear equation (by ruler) or quadratic equation (by circle,  hence by compass), or a combination thereof is possible. It is shown in many places (particularly, chap 15 of Hungerford's book on Abstract Algebra 3rd edn), but particularly in a geometry book it is shown in prominence in book by Sylvester (pg 18,19) at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXOFf.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r1Pl.png

Comment: Please state which graphic s/w is used to draw the image above. Also, would like to experiment with, if is open-source. I would request doubts raised in the first & second edit. I was unable to show congruence in the answer by 'egreg' for the issue raised in the first edit for part(a); while the second edit is too confusing to me, as to say that double bisecting leads to trisecting is not clear. I am sorry, as of now am not able to distinguish your answer for approach (b) with the second edit's contents, which I have treated as an explanation for approach (b).

Comment: Sorry, the book's author is 'Silvester' (John R. Silvester), & not 'Sylvester'.

Comment: I use desmos.com. .... $(b)$ and your second edit are totally approach. Method $(b)$ doesn't even cross over to the other side and method $(b)$ is wrong. egreg's method is faster. For figure $3.13$, note that $\triangle CDO$, $\triangle DOE$, $\triangle EOB$ are all equilateral. $\angle AOE = 90^\circ - \angle EOB = 30^\circ$.

Comment: i mean method $(b)$ and your second edit are totally different.

Comment: Please tell the reason for the 'Edit 2' statement from the book, as in the image on pg #53 that the bisection of bisected smaller interval leads to trisection.

Comment: It just says that if $\theta$ can be trisected, then $\frac{\theta}{2}$ can be trisected as well. To do so, just do $\frac{\theta}{3}$ first and then bisect the angle obtained, hence we have trisected $\frac{\theta}2$.  Similarly,we can see by induction that we can trisect any $\frac{\theta}{2^n}$ is $\theta$ can be trisected.

Comment: Thanks for removing that error due to my lack. I just found an article for a simpler (not involving abstract algebra) algebraic explanation of the impossibility of solving the arbitrary angle trisection problem by unmarked ruler and collapsing compass (i.e., cannot measure/remember length by that).It covers which mechanisms can do, and their algebraic reasons too. It is at: https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED058058.pdf

Comment: In the article stated in my previous comment (https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED058058.pdf), it is given on page #9, that the range of $x$ lies between $+2$ and $-2$. I can easily see that $x=+2$ when $3\theta = 90^o$. But, how to check for case $x=-2$ is not clear. Also, can I use desmos.com to help me see 'this' variation in the value of $x$ (or by any other open-source s/w), by plotting some parametrized set of linear equations. If it is shown to me, then would not only invoke a lot of interest, but also would make a lot many ideas to come forth.

Comment: $x=2\cos \theta$, consider the range of $\cos$ to deduced possible range of $x$.

Comment: For the Fig. 1 in the stated article (https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED058058.pdf) in my earlier comment, the parametric form suggested by you is not helping, as need have edges, vertices, & variation in edge lengths (due to change in position of vertices) by change in chosen (by me) parameter $\theta=\{0^0,\pi \}$. Am unable to plot as at: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dq3vw1enny. Unable to plot any length. My useless analysis is in the next comment.

Comment: Point $C=(0,0)$, angle $\theta =\{0^0, \pi\}$, edges $OA, CD, OD=1$. 
Edge $ON=a= cos 3\theta, AL=Y=\cos 2\theta, CA= 1+2\cos 2\theta$. Edges that change are: (i)$DL$,(ii)$ LA$, (iii)$ON$, (iv) $CM$, (v)$MO$. So, will describe the points, and then describe the equations of the edges. The points are : (i) $C= (0,0)$, (ii) $O= (2\cos \theta, 0)$, (iii)$D= (x/2, sin\theta)$, (iv) $N= (2\cos \theta + \cos 3\theta, 0)$. $A, L$ will be in terms of the edge lengths $CA, CL$ only. These are : $CA= \frac{(x+a)}{\cos \theta} = \frac{(2\cos \theta+\cos 3\theta)}{\cos \theta}$; so $CA=x+a$,(iv)$OA=\dots$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75826/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten).

Comment: Please join the chat room, for some important updates on the issue.

Comment: I have installed Anaconda, and will be shortly running sample numpy, scipy codes. Please see the power of desmos at: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/demlnm4jyb. Hope that this running desmos code will after familiarity with scipy numpy form the basis of the program used to run in Anaconda based terminal the similar graphics program. I hope that for future, for such simpler exercises in geometry, desmos will help to find runnable and valid code, and make it easy to port/transfer then to python on anaconda. As an aside, can trim (will try) infinite length of straight lines based on $x$ limits.

Comment: [truncation of length](https://support.desmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/202528949-Domain-and-Range-Restrictions) but yup, this is no longer maths but programming issue.

Comment: Have graph at: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/smdxtyiom9, for the image at : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj0pB.png, taken from :   http://www.lamath.org/journal/Vol1/trisection_using_bisection.pdf; that deals with "Edit 3" above. It limits the y-coordinate at $x=b/3$ to be within the the lune (formed by the intersecting circles) for the changing values of $b$. Regarding the stated planned earlier change for limiting edge length, I have new graph at :https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nrcfmtxdtp.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Consider]

The line $AB$ is perpendicular to $BC$. The circles have, respectively, centers $B$ and $C$ and radius $BC$. The segments $BD$, $BC$ and $CD$ are equal by construction. Can you prove that the angle $\widehat{CBD}$ is twice the angle $\widehat{DBA}$?

Comment: The angle $\widehat{CBD}=60^o$, while the angle $\widehat{CBA}=90^o$, so the remaining angle of the difference, i.e. $\widehat{DBA}= 30^o$. But, the next step is missing to me, that will help in solving the issue. May be, you have meant that in the reference in the 'Edit' of the O.P., the angle $\widehat{AOE}$ is similarly of $30^o$. But, how to make triangles' congruence (between : $\triangle DCO $ & $\triangle DOE$)  is not clear.

Comment: For proving the congruence of $\triangle DCO$ & $\triangle DOE$, first need to show that the base $DC = DO$, as the side $DO$ is common. But, even that will not work, as the contained angle in those sides cannot be taken to be equal, as a part of that is to be proved to be $30^o$. It is totally confusing. Please help.

Comment: @jiten Do the same construction on the opposite side of $BC$.

Comment: Have done the same construction on the opposite side of $BC$ as shown at:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/wulZN.png, but was unable to create triangles by that. So, did the same construction symmetrically at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLV5P.png But, how would that help in finding congruence between triangles $\triangle DCO$ & $\triangle DOE$ is not clear.

Comment: Did you hear the Origami method of paper folding to trisect a given  angle?

Comment: @Narasimham NO, but will read it. I hope once read, will make this problem easier.

Comment: @jiten I meant doing a symmetry with axis $AB$